# ошибка импорта BaseFilter из aiogram

Tags: python, импорт, aiogram-2.x

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import BaseFilter
from aiogram.types import Message


class IsMedia(BaseFilter):
    IsMedia: bool


    async def __call__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        self.is_media = message.media_group_id is not None
        return self.is_media
```

Comment: пробывал искать фильтр в папке,  не  нашёл

Comment: кидай сразу код ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вы используете aiogram 3.x.
Попробуйте заменить так:

```py
from aiogram.filters.base import Filter as BaseFilter
from aiogram.types import Message


class IsMedia(BaseFilter):
    is_media: bool


    async def __call__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        self.is_media = message.media_group_id is not None
        return self.is_media
```

Comment: попробовал, выдал ошибку  No module named 'aiogram.filters'

Comment: попробовал вот так:  from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import filters as BaseFilter, вроде получилось, но выдало другую  ошибку :module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 0):

обнови aiogram до 3:    pip install aiogram==3.0.0b3

Answer (score 0):

Тебе для решения этой проблемы нужно обновить aiogram до последней версии, а делается это так(на Windows по крайней мере):

```
pip install aiogram==3.4.1
```